# behavior of read from unistd.h

Tags: c++, multithreading, unistd.h

I have code that reads from a file descriptor with `read` from `unistd.h`. I'm getting strange behavior where the thread encountering `read` exits, and I can't find anything in the documentation that would explain this.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

I'm not sure if posting code would help, there's a lot of unrelated code snippets, but here's a stripped down version:

My initialization of the file descriptor:

(`m_serialFD` is a member of type `int` and this takes place in a constructor)

```
m_serialFD = open("/dev/ttymxc0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
// flag setting code here....
```

Later in the constructor, I initialize a mutex member variable:

```
pthread_mutex_init (&m_serialMutex, NULL);
```

Later in a member function:

(`message` is just an array of `chars` `nBytes` long)

```
pthread_mutex_lock (&m_serialMutex);
// write some stuff then get the response
read (m_serialFD, message, nBytes);
pthread_mutex_unlock (&m_serialMutex);
```

I lock a mutex around the read calls because I've got multiple member functions making reads and writes and I don't want responses to get mixed up. One thing I've noticed is that when I run this code with only one thread reading from m_serialFD, I have no problems, but multiple threads causes the exiting behavior.

Comment: how do you know there is an exit?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I know there is an exit because I debug with gdb. When I let the code run, I see the message: [Thread 0x265c8460 (LWP 3897) exited]

Comment: Did you initialize the mutex?

Comment: @villekulla yes in the constructor, I've edited the post to show how it was done specifically.

Comment: No possible way to answer this without seeing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), from the code you posted there are already some errors (such as not checking the return from `read()`) which doesn't bode well for the rest of the code. There's no way to answer without code which will reproduce your problem.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I understand, I actually do check the return value, but it doesn't make it past that call anyway, so I never get to see it. This code talks to some specialized hardware that expects particular formats for input. I don't have access to the drivers, so a self-contained example would be difficult to put together.

Comment: @MikeP.: `read()` works the same way for all files, you could put a short example together that uses the same code structure you have now, but reads from a regular file, and see if you get the same problem. If that works, then the chances are pretty good it's nothing to do with `read()`. At a minimum, we'd have a compilable example that we could at least look at for glaring errors.